# PYTHON string with variables in Enum

Tags: python, string, templates, enums

I am trying to do something like this:

```
class SomeEnum(str, Enum):
    STRING_A = 'This is a string A with variable ' + variable
    STRING_B = 'This is a string B with variable ' + variable
```

and use it like a template, for instance:

```
some_list.append(SomeEnum.STRING_A(variable))
```

is this even possible in Enums since it defies the purpose of Enums a bit? Or what else would you suggest instead of Enums? Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"since it defies the purpose of Enums"* — Indeed it does. What's the use case for this exactly…?!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say define a `__call__` method along with some string formatting

```
class SomeEnum(str, Enum):
    STRING_A = 'This is a string A with variable %s %s '
    STRING_B = 'This is a string B with variable %s %s'

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self % args

print(SomeEnum.STRING_A("a", "b"))  # This is a string A with variable a b
print(SomeEnum.STRING_B("c", "d"))  # This is a string B with variable c d
```

The only rule : provide the same amount of paramater, as the string expects

---

Dynamic formatting

```
class SomeEnum(str, Enum):
    STRING_A = 'This is a string A with variable '
    STRING_B = 'This is a string B with variable '

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            return self + args[0]
        return self + ', '.join(args[:-1]) + " and " + args[-1]


print(SomeEnum.STRING_A("a"))            # This is a string A with variable a
print(SomeEnum.STRING_B("a", "b"))       # This is a string B with variable a and b
print(SomeEnum.STRING_B("a", "b", "c"))  # This is a string B with variable a, b and c
```

Comment: What if I need it to be like:
```
STRING_A = 'This is a string A {variableA} and {variableB}  '
```

Comment: in that case you would need to know the position of `variableA` and `variableB`, it's possible but why would you want that?

Comment: @cassham see the edit, do you need something that accepts any amount of parameter and give a specific output ?

Comment: for custom error messages - now they are very generic, like "the first value should be bigger than the second" but i need to do "value X is less than Y, change that" (or something along the lines) and till now enums are used, and its more convenient for testing and stuff i guess.

@azro It is either 2 parameters or nothing (some strings dont need those variables)

Answer (score 0):

No!. You can't do like that. It is not practical. The code you're writing cannot see `intellisense`. If you want to see it in public, then you can use `self`.

```
class SomeEnum:

    def __init__(self, enum):
        self.Enum = enum
        self.STRING_A = f'This is a string A with variable {enum}'
        self.STRING_B = f'This is a string B with variable {enum}'


num = 6

p1 = SomeEnum(num)

print(p1.STRING_A)
print(p1.STRING_B)
```